# LWC: How to update record with values selected in Multi-Select lookup

Tags: lightning-web-components, lookup, lightning-quickaction

I have a requirement where a user needs to be able to select multiples accounts from a lookup field. It seems that it is only possible using a LWC.
I was able to implement the first part of the logic of the LWC component. here I am calling the multiSelectLookup component from a parent component using a quick action
[image]

```
<template>
    <lightning-quick-action-panel header="Mettre à jour - Chirurgie faite dans le centre">
        <lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordId}
                                    object-api-name={objectApiName}
                                    onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Chirurgie_faite_dans_le_centre__c"></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Performance_Level__c"></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Autre_centre_chirurgie_principal__c"></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Autre_centre_chirurgie_secondaire__c"></lightning-input-field>
            <c-lwc-multi-select-lookup object-name="Account" onselectedrecord={handleSelectedRecord}></c-lwc-multi-select-lookup><br>
            <lightning-button variant="neutral" label="Cancel"></lightning-button>
            <lightning-button variant="brand" class="slds-var-m-left_x-small" label="Save" type="submit"></lightning-button>
            
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
        
    </lightning-quick-action-panel>
</template>
```

The problem is that currently I am not storing and saving the multiple records selected on the current record. So obviously, when I click save or refresh, the multiple accounts selected (Tenet Corporation, MHA Media, Umbrella Corp) will disappear. These 3 accounts won't appear when opening the quick action again

On the multiSelectLookup component, we get the selected records in selectedRecords list.

```
@track selectedRecords = [];

setSelectedRecord(event) {
        var recId = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
        var selectName = event.currentTarget.dataset.name;
        let newsObject = { 'recId' : recId ,'recName' : selectName };
        this.selectedRecords.push(newsObject);
        this.txtclassname =  'slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click';
        let selRecords = this.selectedRecords;
        this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input').forEach(each => {
            each.value = '';
        });
        const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('selected', { detail: {selRecords}, });
        // Dispatches the event.
        this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
    }
```

I believe that is what I need to use to actually store the values on the current record.
I created on text area field to possibly store the Id of the records select on the multiSelectLookup component, but I'm really not sure how to go about it

here are the components:
**LwcMultiSelectLookup**

```
import { LightningElement,api,track } from 'lwc';
import getResults from '@salesforce/apex/lwcMultiLookupController.getResults';

export default class LwcMultiSelectLookup extends LightningElement {
    @api objectName = 'Account';
    @api fieldName = 'Name';
    @api Label;
    @track searchRecords = [];
    @track selectedRecords = [];
    @api required = false;
    @api iconName = 'action:new_account'
    @api LoadingText = false;
    @track txtclassname = 'slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click';
    @track messageFlag = false;
 
    searchField(event) {

        var currentText = event.target.value;
        var selectRecId = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < this.selectedRecords.length; i++){
            selectRecId.push(this.selectedRecords[i].recId);
        }
        this.LoadingText = true;
        getResults({ ObjectName: this.objectName, fieldName: this.fieldName, value: currentText, selectedRecId : selectRecId })
        .then(result => {
            this.searchRecords= result;
            this.LoadingText = false;
            
            this.txtclassname =  result.length > 0 ? 'slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click slds-is-open' : 'slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click';
            if(currentText.length > 0 && result.length == 0) {
                this.messageFlag = true;
            }
            else {
                this.messageFlag = false;
            }

            if(this.selectRecordId != null && this.selectRecordId.length > 0) {
                this.iconFlag = false;
                this.clearIconFlag = true;
            }
            else {
                this.iconFlag = true;
                this.clearIconFlag = false;
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('-------error-------------'+error);
            console.log(error);
        });
        
    }
    
   setSelectedRecord(event) {
        var recId = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
        var selectName = event.currentTarget.dataset.name;
        let newsObject = { 'recId' : recId ,'recName' : selectName };
        this.selectedRecords.push(newsObject);
        this.txtclassname =  'slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click';
        let selRecords = this.selectedRecords;
        this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input').forEach(each => {
            each.value = '';
        });
        const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('selected', { detail: {selRecords}, });
        // Dispatches the event.
        this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
    }

    removeRecord (event){
        let selectRecId = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < this.selectedRecords.length; i++){
            if(event.detail.name !== this.selectedRecords[i].recId)
                selectRecId.push(this.selectedRecords[i]);
        }
        this.selectedRecords = [...selectRecId];
        let selRecords = this.selectedRecords;
        const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('selected', { detail: {selRecords}, });
        // Dispatches the event.
        this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
    }
}
```

**lwcQuickAction.html**

```
<template>
    <lightning-quick-action-panel header="Mettre à jour - Chirurgie faite dans le centre">
        <lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordId}
                                    object-api-name={objectApiName}
                                    onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Chirurgie_faite_dans_le_centre__c"></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Performance_Level__c"></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Autre_centre_chirurgie_principal__c"></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Autre_centre_chirurgie_secondaire__c"></lightning-input-field>
            <c-lwc-multi-select-lookup object-name="Account" onselectedrecord={handleSelectedRecord}></c-lwc-multi-select-lookup><br>
            <lightning-button variant="neutral" label="Cancel"></lightning-button>
            <lightning-button variant="brand" class="slds-var-m-left_x-small" label="Save" type="submit"></lightning-button>
            
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
        
    </lightning-quick-action-panel>
</template>
```

**lwcQuickAction.js**

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { CloseActionScreenEvent } from 'lightning/actions';

export default class LwcQuickAction extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;
    
    handleSelectedRecord(event) {
        this.selectedRecords = event.detail;
    }

    handleSuccess(e) {
        // Close the modal window and display a success toast
        this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success',
                message: 'Record updated!',
                variant: 'success'
            })
        );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already storing the Id values in the TextAreaField__c of the record, get the Records using this field from Apex callout.

Use below Apex method. Pass the **recordId** as parameter and get the Id and Name of the records stored in the TextAreaField__c field.

```js
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Account> getMultiLookupRecords( String recordId ) {
    Schema.SObjectType sobjectType = recordId.getSObjectType();
    String sobjectName = sobjectType.getDescribe().getName();

    //get record that stores Account Id values in TextAreaField__c
    SObject record = Database.query('Select Id, TextAreaField__c From ' + sobjectName + ' Where Id = :recordId');
    
    List<String> idList = record.TextAreaField__c.split(','); //assuming comma separator in TextAreaField__c Id values
    return [
        SELECT Id, Name
        FROM Account
        WHERE Id IN: idList
    ];
}
```

---

Call the Apex method as Wired callout in **lwcQuickAction.js**
Get the records and store in the local property `selectedRecords`

```js
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { CloseActionScreenEvent } from 'lightning/actions';
import getMultiLookupRecords from '@salesforce/apex/ApexClassName.getMultiLookupRecords';


export default class LwcQuickAction extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;
    
    selectedRecords = []
    
    @wire(getMultiLookupRecords , { recordId: '$recordId' })
    wiredRecordsMethod({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.handleSelectedData([...data])
        } else if (error) {
            //handle error
        }
    }
    
    handleSelectedData(data){
        let selectedRecords = []
        if(data && data.length){
            data.foreach((element)=>{
                selectedRecords.push({'recId' : element.Id ,'recName' : element.Name})
            })
        }
        this.selectedRecords = selectedRecords
    }
    
    handleSelectedRecord(event) {
        this.selectedRecords = event.detail;
    }

    handleSuccess(e) {
        // Close the modal window and display a success toast
        this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success',
                message: 'Record updated!',
                variant: 'success'
            })
        );
   }
}
```

---

Pass this local property to **LwcMultiSelectLookup** in **lwcQuickAction.html**

```html
<c-lwc-multi-select-lookup object-name="Account" onselectedrecord={handleSelectedRecord} selected={selectedRecords}></c-lwc-multi-select-lookup>
```

---

Use Getter-setter in **LwcMultiSelectLookup.js** to set the local `selectedRecords` So the selected records which are stored in database will be passed to the LwcMultiSelectLookup component.

```js
@api
get selected() {
    return this.selectedRecords;
}

set selected(value) {
   this.selectedRecords = value ?? []
}
```

Comment: hi @sneh, thank you very much for your reply. Just the currently I am not able to store the values (AccountIds) on the textArea field. But judging from your answer, once I managed to put in place that logic to store AccountIds in the textArea field. That should solve the issue, correct?

Comment: Yes it will solve the issue.